# TPopupMenu.Popup on system tray appears in wrong position

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm creating a Tray Icon for my Firemonkey (XE7) application, and there is an issue with calling `TrayMenu.Popup(Screen.MousePos.X,Screen.MousePos.Y);`

The popup menu will appear at my cursor, except when my cursor is on the Tray Icon for my application. The popup menu appears quite far above the actual tray, leaving a large space, like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is surely by design. Nobody wants a menu obscuring the taskbar. Also, should you be using MousePos? Doesn't the event come with an associated position.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Have you ever right clicked an application on the taskbar? They always appear right above your cursor, its natural behavior of all tray applications. As for MousePos, the cursor position is not passed via the Wnd event message.

Comment: Sounds like this is a feature of FMX then. All part of the game with non-native development.